# Replace element of a pointer array

Tags: c++

I've an array of pointers `Line* lines[MAX_LINES];`. If I replace an element in the given array `lines[i] = new Line()` do I've to call `delete lines[i]` before or will it be called implicit?

Comment: If you've explicitly created the array members with `new`, then you need to explicitly clear them with `delete`. Else it's implicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer

You have to explicitly call `delete` on it, before replacing it, to avoid memory leaks. This assuming every `Line` in the array is dynamically allocated using `new`.

#### Alternative with smart pointers

The optimal solution would be to simply use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in conjunction with a smart pointer, like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (for shared resources) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (for exclusive ownership):

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<Line>, MAX_LINES> lines;
// ...
lines[i] = new Line()
```

This is done via the overloaded [`std::unique_ptr::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) which automatically releases the resource before assigning a new one.

#### Simpler alternative

A much simpler alternative (and probably much more efficient too, given that you are storing all the lines contiguously and caches love that) is to simply use an `std::vector<Line>` and overload `operator=` for `Line`, so that:

```
std::vector<Line> lines;
// ...
lines[i] = Lines(...);
```

will be a valid call.

Comment: I'm new in the C++ World. How does the overloading for `operator=` look like?

Comment: It seems that I don't need to overload the `operator=` but I cannot use `lines[i] = Lines(...);`. I get `vector subscript out of range`

Comment: @messy An `operator=` is implicitly declared (unless specific situations happen). The "vector subscript out of range" is because apparently you are accessing the vector outside of your boundaries. Can I see a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I'm too stupid to get the code in a code block...

`class TextLayer
    {
    public:
     void writeLine(int line, std::string text);
    private:
     std::vector<int> lines;
    };

    void TextLayer::writeLine(int line, std::string description)
    {
     line_amounts[line] = amount;
    }`

The function will be called after an event (mouse click) occured.